# Why are the code colours different for every line in my Jupyter (Ubuntu)?

Tags: python, ubuntu, ipython, jupyter

I was using Jupyter in Windows and just switched to Ubuntu. I found the colour of the code is very weird in the firefox browser. E.g. it highlights the variables in every other line.

I tried to solve this problem by [installing a custom theme](http://github.com/dunovank/jupyter-themes/blob/master/README.md) and the effect should be like

[image]

Instead, it still highlights every other variable on my side, like

[image]

This just makes my eyes very tired when try to debug the code.

I also tried disabling all the add-ons in Firefox which didn't help. Is there any setting that I can change to restore to the default colour display?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I sometimes get this if I'm copying/pasting from a source that has a different indentation size than that of the jupyter notebook. In your screenshot it looks like a small indent size so this seems like the likely culprit. Try highlighting the full block of indented code and hitting `ctrl+[` then `ctrl+]` (this unindents the selected lines of code, then reindents them using the jupyter indent size).

If this doesn't work, you might try checking to see if there are any custom indentation settings specified in either ".jupyter/nbconfig/notebook.json" or ".jupyter/custom/custom.js" (... or whatever the Windows equivalents are).

In ".jupyter/nbconfig/notebook.json", I have the indentUnit set to 4 spaces (and have also enabled linewrapping).

```
{
  "CodeCell": {
    "cm_config": {
      "indentUnit": 4,
      "lineWrapping":true
    }
  }
}
```

Most editors allow you to set your indent size (Atom, sublime text, etc.) so you can avoid this issue in the future by making sure you have the same indent size everywhere you're swapping code to/from (assuming this is what's causing the red highlighting). Python's default is 4 so def recommend sticking with that.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. It turned out it is the indent that caused the issue. I verified this by using Ctrl+[ and Ctrl+].
Since I have the whole piece of code that need to change, so I used your second method. I didn't have the .json files under .jupyter folder and I created the ".jupyter/nbconfig/notebook.json" file and put in the commands you gave. I changed the indent to 2 and the highlight is gone now. I will change that back to 4 when I start a new code. Thanks!